# Error showing variable not initialized when clear initialization exists

Tags: java, variables, methods, bluej

I'm trying to compile my main class but my variable average seems to not bee initialized. My Student class compiles with no errors, but I am having issues figuring out how to get my methods in my main class to function properly. What am I doing wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

Main Class:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class StudentTester {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Student student1 = new Student();
    Student student2 = new Student();
    Student student3 = new Student();


    int score1, score2, score3;
    int score;
    int average;






    String firstName;
    String lastName;

    //start first student here 
    firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the student's first name.");
    student1.setFirstName(firstName);

    lastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the student's last name.");
    student1.setLastName(lastName);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Student 1 has name "
            + student1.getFirstName() + ""+ student1.getLastName() + ".");

    score = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the 1st student's 1st score."));

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Student 1 has average score " + average);
            average = (score1 + score2 + score3);



    //start second student here
    firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the student's first name.");
    student2.setFirstName(firstName);

    lastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the student's last name.");
    student2.setLastName(lastName);


    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Student 2 has name "
            + student2.getFirstName() + "" + student2.getLastName() + ".");

    score = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the 2nd student's 1st score."));

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Student 2 has average score " + average);
        average = (score1 + score2 + score3);




    //start third student here
    firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the student's first name.");
    student3.setFirstName(firstName);

    lastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the student's last name.");
    student3.setLastName(lastName);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Student3 has name "
            + student3.getFirstName() + "" + student3.getLastName() + ".");

    score = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the 3rd student's 1st score."));

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Student 3 has average score " + average);
        average = (score1 + score2 + score3);

    //average score
    score = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the 1st student's score"));



        }
    }
```

Student Class:

```
public class Student {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private int score1, score2, score3;
private int average;



public void setFirstName(String name){
    firstName = name;
}
public String getFirstName(){
    return firstName;
}
public void setLastName(String name){
    lastName = name;
}
public String getLastName(){
    return lastName;
}
public void setScore1(String newvalue){
    score1 = Integer.parseInt(newvalue);
}
public int getScore1(int newvalue){
    return score1;
}
public void setScore2(String newvalue){
    score2 = Integer.parseInt(newvalue);
}
public int getScore2(int newvalue){
    return score2;
}
public void setScore3(String newvalue){
    score3 = Integer.parseInt(newvalue);
}
public int getScore3(int newvalue){
    return score3;
}
public int setAverage(int newvalue){
    average = (score1 + score2 + score3)/3;
    return average;
}
public int getAverage(String newvalue){
    return average;
} 
}
```

Comment: You never set score1, score2 or score3. Instead, your code uses (repeatedly) `score`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch made the suggested changes and still ran into the same error when compiling.

Comment: You still never set `scoreX`, and since when is an average a sum?

Answer (score 1):

```
score = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the 1st student's 1st score."));

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Student 1 has average score " + average);
        average = (score1 + score2 + score3);
```

You try to display `average` in the line before it's initialized; additionally, at no point have score1, score2 or score3 been initialized. Rather than having variables in your `StudentTester` try:

Main Class

```
student1.setScore1(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the 1st student's 1st score."));
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, student1.getName() + " has average score " + student1.getAverage();
```

Student Class

```
public int getAverage()
{
    if (score1 == null) score1 = 0;
    if (score2 == null) score2 = 0;
    if (score3 == null) score3 = 0;

    return (score1 + score2 + score3) / 3;
}

public string getName()
{
    if (firstName == null) firstName = "";
    if (lastName == null) lastName = "";
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
}
```

This puts the student-based logic in the Student class.  You can improve greatly on the simple null checks here, but you I'm demonstrating a more object-oriented approach.

Comment: Perhaps you've changed that from `score` to `score1`, but you're still trying to show `average` in the dialog *before* setting it to `(score1 + score2 + score3)`, while `score2` and `score3` are also still uninitialized.

Comment: `        `score1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the 1st student's 1st score."));`
        
        `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Student 1 has average score` `" + average);`
                `average = (score1 + score2 + score3);`  I changed `score` to `score`  initializing the variable and setting it to an Integer, correct? I still get the same error message.

Comment: Yes, but before you even get to `score1` not being initialized you have an attempt to read `average` by `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()` before it has been initialized (and the initialization call on the following line will still fail because `score2` and `score3` are not yet initialized).